# With Dalli, what do you set for Key & Secret?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, memcached

In the docs:
https://github.com/mperham/dalli

You set:

```
# Session cache / Memcache
ActionController::Base.session = {
  :namespace   => 'sessions',
  :expire_after => 20.minutes.to_i,
  :memcache_server => ['server-1:11211', 'server-2:11211'],
  :key         => ...,
  :secret      => ...
}
```

What do you set for Key and Secret?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I presume you are configuring Dalli as your session store.

For the secret token, you can use the token that you would have already specified in `config/initializers/secret_token.rb` Or you can use random text like `:secret => "extraterrestrialactivityfoundinbermudatriangle"`

As for the key, it would normally contain your app name `:key => "_my_app_name_session"`